# php snippet breaks down the site

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

My products have a custom meta `'wccaf_virtual_quantity'`. Now I want to calculate and add another custom meta 'actual_stock'. Value of `'actual_stock'` = `stock` - `wccaf_virtual_quantity`
The code I am trying breaks down my site It gives error of `'The site is experiencing technical difficulties. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.'` while accessing admin panel. but when I disable the code from the database and check the products table for `'actual_stock'`, I can see the values of `'actual_stock'` are updated. 
That means the code works as it should but it breaks down the site in process.

I have tried adding following code to `functions.php`. I am adding php snippet using 'Code Snippets' plugin

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
$products_array = get_posts($args);

if (!empty($products_array)) {
// loop through each product
foreach ($products_array as $product)
{
    update_actual_stock($product->ID);
}
}

function update_actual_stock($post_id) {
$post_type = get_post_type($post_id);

if ($post_type == 'product') {
    $product = wc_get_product($post_id);

    $virtual_stock = get_post_meta( $post_id, 
'wccaf_virtual_quantity', true );
    $visible_stock = $product->get_stock_quantity();
    $actual_quantity = $visible_stock - $virtual_stock;   

    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'actual_stock',$actual_quantity);   
}
}
```

Please check what am I doing wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by 'breaks down my site'? As in, it does nothing?

Comment: 'Break down' means when I try to access my admin panel I get this message `'The site is experiencing technical difficulties. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.'`

Comment: That sounds like a custom error message for a basic 500 Internal Server error, so go check the log files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have to run the function on every request?

Off-course, your code can kill your server, its being triggered for every request either admin or front-end, and its queries and loops through all posts then update all product post,

You should hook it somewhere, like when post is created/updated

checkout [save_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) function

```
//Your function to update the meta
function update_actual_stock($post_id) {
    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);

    if ($post_type == 'product') {
        $product = wc_get_product($post_id);

        $virtual_stock = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'wccaf_virtual_quantity', true );
        $visible_stock = $product->get_stock_quantity();
        $actual_quantity = $visible_stock - $virtual_stock;   
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'actual_stock',$actual_quantity);   
    }
}


// hook it on 'save_post' action hook so it only updates meta of specific post if its updated/created
function _update_blabla_meta( $post_id ) {
    update_actual_stock($post_id)
}
add_action( 'save_post', '_update_blabla_meta' );
```

if you need your function to run after order is place you have to hook it on `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed`, there are three parameter being pass on that action `do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', $order_id, $posted_data, $order );` for you to grab which post to update

check the code here https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Checkout.html#1120

**EDIT....**

This should achieve what you want, or simply modify it to suit your needs;

```
//run meta update on products only after order is place
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', function($order_id) {

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); // get the order from ID
    $items = $order->get_items(); // get order items

    //Loop through order each items
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {

        $porduct_id = $item->get_product_id(); //get the product ID from order item

        $virtual_stock = get_post_meta( $porduct_id, 'wccaf_virtual_quantity', true ); // get your own meta value

        $visible_stock = get_post_meta( $porduct_id, '_stock', true ); // get the product current stock count

        $actual_quantity = $visible_stock - $virtual_stock;   

        update_post_meta( $porduct_id, 'actual_stock', $actual_quantity); // Update your own meta
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok, the case is I need to update all products 'Actual Stock' meta values when ever a order is placed.

Comment: Or can I update all products `'Actual Stock'` meta value whenever I open products table from admin panel ?

Comment: I dont understand why would you want to update ALL products even those thats aren't touch?  as far as my understanding of your goal, you should only update products that are being ordered.

Comment: Yes, I think that's correct. I need to update only those products which are ordered.

Comment: now if I want to update the products from a order should I put the array inside `_update_blabla_meta`?

Comment: I've edited my answer again according to your needs